# setInterval in a jQuery each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, setinterval

I think i'm making a dumb mistake here, but I don't see it.  I'm trying to get a list of <li>s and use a setInterval to operate on each of them, but the setInterval isn't behaving the way I'd expect.

Snippet of my markup:

```
<ul>
  <li id="thing1"></li>
  <li id="thing2"></li>
  <li id="thing3"></li>
</ul>
```

Snippet of my Javascript:

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
  button = $(this).attr("id");
  setInterval(function(){console.log(button);}, 500);
});
```

What I would like/expect console output to be:

```
thing1
thing2
thing3
(repeating 500ms)
```

But what I actually get:

```
thing1
thing1
thing1
(repeating 500ms)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is it a scope thing?

Comment: classic problem when you neglect to use `var`, you get unexpected situations occurring. The global variable is changed by the time the interval elapses

Comment: Not sure why my question is being downvoted?  Is it not valid?

Comment: Consider using a tool like http://jshint.com to help you find common coding errors.

Comment: And use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")`. No need for jQuery there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code fragment repeated here:

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
  button = $(this).attr("id");
  setInterval(function(){console.log(button);}, 500);
});
```

You are using the variable "button" as a global variable and there is only one instance of it.  This means that it is will have just one value.  What you probably want is:

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
  var button = $(this).attr("id");
  setInterval(function(){console.log(button);}, 500);
});
```

which will create a local variable to your `each()` callback function that will be in closure scope for your `setInterval()` callback function.

Answer (score 2):

It's a "you forgot to declare 'button' as a local variable" thing.

```
var button = $(this).attr("id");
```

Without that, the variable is **global**.

Comment: That is indeed my problem!  Thank you.